# hadoop file system list my own root directory

Tags: hadoop, installation, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I met a very wired situation when I try to install single node hadoop yarn 2.2.0 on my mac. I follow the tutorial on this link: http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/.

When I start the hadoop, and jps to check the status, it shows: (which means normal, I think)

```
5552 Jps
7162 ResourceManager
7512 Jps
7243 NodeManager
6962 DataNode
7060 SecondaryNameNode
6881 NameNode
```

However, after enter

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

The files lists are the files in my own root but not the hadoop file system root. There must be some error when I set the hadoop that mix my own fs with the hdfs. Could any one give me a hint about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command for accessing HDFS

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
```

Or

Populate ${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/core-site.xml as follows. If your doing so even without specifying hdfs:// URI you will be able to access HDFS.

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Add the following line at the starting of the file `$HOME/yarn/hadoop-2.0.1-alpha/libexec/hadoop-config.sh`

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/yarn/hadoop-2.0.1-alpha/etc/hadoop
```

Comment: I have used your second method, and try hadoop fs -ls /. It still shows the list of my root dir

Comment: Were you able to access HDFS with method 1 ?. If that is working Use the modified method 2 inorder to access hdfs without specifying URI

Comment: Yes, it works fine with method1! I just want to know why it does not work with second methods...

Comment: Earlier even if we modify core-site.xml file, it was not in CLASSPATH, Whatever values we are specifying in the environment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR will be loaded into CLASSPATH